# How I make a logo and actionBar transparent?

Tags: android, png, android-actionbar

I am using a .png for both my logo and action Bar menu items. I am using the **android.Holo.light** theme.

Even though I've made the background transparent for both the logo and the menu items, a grey shaded area is still showing behind the .png. How do I change this?

Take a look at my menu XML and my style override XML below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
  <style name="MyTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light">
     <item name="android:selectableItemBackground">@color/transparent</item>
     <item name="android:background">#00000000</item>
  </style>

  <style name="ActionBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar" >
      <item name="android:selectableItemBackground">@color/transparent</item>
      <item name="android:background">#00000000</item>

  </style>

  <style name="textTitle" 
      parent="@android:style/TextAppearance">
    <item name="android:textSize">20dp</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#DC0451</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
  </style>


   <style name="textDescription" 
      parent="@android:style/TextAppearance">
    <item name="android:textSize">15dp</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#666666</item>
  </style>
</resources>
```

- **Menu xml**

  ```
      <item 
          android:id="@+id/Category"
          android:title="Category"
          android:showAsAction="always|withText"
          android:icon="@drawable/menuitemselect"
          style="@style/ActionBar"

          > 
           <menu>
                <item     
                  android:id="@+id/catalog"
                  android:title="Main Catalog"
                  android:icon="@drawable/menuitemselect"
                  android:onClick="catalogClick"
              />
              <item android:id="@+id/newvideos"
                  android:title="New"
                  android:icon="@drawable/menuitemselect"
                  android:onClick="newVideoClick"
                  style="@style/ActionBar"
              />


               <item 
                  android:id="@+id/popularvideos"
                  android:title="Popular"
                  android:icon="@drawable/menuitemselect" 
                  android:onClick="popularVideoClick"
                  style="@style/ActionBar"
               />

           </menu>

    </item>

              <item android:id="@+id/backButton"
                  android:title="Back"
                  android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
                  android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
              />

  </menu>
  ```

Thank you

Comment: OVerride the theme and set your own android:background to whatever you want

Comment: I've tried, take a look at my edits above.

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of what you are seeing?

Comment: I found that the issue was with : <item name="android:selectableItemBackground">@color/transparent</item>. I added it in  an attempt to get rid of default highlight feature.  It seems when I have this set, the grey background shows up. When I remove it, it acts as it should.

Comment: I will try to find another way to get rid of the selectableItem highlight.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found that the issue was with :

```
 <item name="android:selectableItemBackground">@color/transparent</item>.
```

I added it in an attempt to get rid of default highlight feature. It seems when I have this set, the grey background shows up. When I remove it, it acts as it should.